# unable to use JSON string in rails method condition statement

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker, parameters

I am having a problem in a rails 3 front controller method. I am building an application that queries a database of cars by a registrationdate that is being selected with the jquery datepicker plugin. I got most parts working except the comparison of my datepicker datestring and the mysql2 database content in the rails method. The query works if i hardcode a string, but not if i pass the variable that i received from the datepicker form.

**_search_by_date_results.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").change(function() {
    var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    date = jQuery.trim(date).substring(0, 10);
    $("#placeholder").text(date);

  $.ajax({
    url : "/search_by_date",
    type : "post",
    data : { date_value: date }
});

}); });
```

The form:

```
<div class="pagetitle_search">
   <p>Date: <br><br><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
   <%= form_tag url_for(:action => "search_by_date"), :remote => true do %>
</div>
<div class="pagetitle_search"><%= submit_tag 'search' %>
</div>
```

**front_controller.rb**

```
def search_by_date 
    date = params[:date_value]
    @vehicle_types = VehicleType.find(:all, :conditions => ["commercialdate Like ?", date])
    render "_search_by_date_results.html.erb"
    end
end
```

In my console i first receive:

Parameters: {"date_value"=>"Thu Feb 05"}
but no output to the view

when i press the search button i get:
   SELECT ... WHERE (commercialdate LIKE NULL)

Any idea what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: The title is slight off since i am using a normal javascript string in the example

Comment: in which format date stored in commercialdate field ?

Comment: Hi. It turned ou that params was not the problem. I got it to work by adding a GET request to my ajax script:

Comment: $.get('/search_by_date', { date_value: date }, function(data) {
            $('#placeholder').html(data);
      });Now i have to make it render nicely in the view